# Merge duplicate text from two columns and put unique text in another column

Tags: openoffice, duplicate

I've got two columns of about 13,000 email addresses. One has members and the other has newsletter subscribers. There are duplicates between the two(ie. a member who also subscribes to the newsletter). Is there a way to take all of the duplicates out of the newsletter emails leaving only the emails unique to the newsletter?

ie.

```
-members-      -newsletter-    OUTPUT-->  -members-      -just newsletter-
foo@foo.com    foo@foo.com                foo@foo.com    bob@foo.com
sally@foo.com  bob@foo.com                sally@foo.com  larry@foo.com
jane@foo.com   larry@foo.com              jane@foo.com
```

So it took out foo@foo.com because it was also a member.